# tabledrag: React on drag event

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a form with tabledrag, with some fancy client-side behavior when (after) a row is being dragged.

More specifically: If row A is being dragged, I want to change an indicators on row B, depending on the new position of row A.

The classical solution would be a jQuery event that fires when a row is dragged. But which event is that, and to which element does it bind?

UPDATE

2pha pointed me to this page, which is nice:
http://drupalapi.attiks.com/api/drupal/misc!tabledrag.js/7

So the remaining question is, how to use these commands?

```
$('table#the-table').onDrag(..)
```

would that be it?

Comment: check [this](http://drupalapi.attiks.com/api/drupal/misc!tabledrag.js/7)

Comment: oh, nice! (didn't notice your comment)

Comment: ok, so how would i use this stuff?

Comment: and if you put this in a real "Answer" i can vote you up :)

Comment: damn, link not working atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer for you! Check out the core tabledrag.js lines 862, 869, 1150, 1160. These are all functions that you can overwrite to react to tabledrag events! Here's a code example I wrote for you:

```
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype.onSwap = function (swappedRow) {
      (function ($) { // Important as this allows $ for jQuery.
        alert('React to tabledrag!');
        return NULL;
      }(jQuery));
    }
```